# How to use function computeCorrespondEpilines() in OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using this code to find epipolar line ([source](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;


int main(){
    int point_count = 8;
    vector<Point2f> points1(point_count);
    vector<Point2f> points2(point_count);

            points1[0] = Point2f(330, 123);
            points1[1] = Point2f(330,240);
            points1[2] = Point2f(260,223);
            points1[3] = Point2f(202,109);
            points1[4] = Point2f(204,207);
            points1[5] = Point2f(118,104);
            points1[6] = Point2f(41,174);
            points1[7] = Point2f(205,209);

            points2[0] = Point2f(268,89);
            points2[1] = Point2f(268,207);
            points2[2] = Point2f(212,191);
            points2[3] = Point2f(164,82);
            points2[4] = Point2f(168,176);
            points2[5] = Point2f(116,74);
            points2[6] = Point2f(29,143);
            points2[7] = Point2f(167,178);


    Mat fundamental_matrix = findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, FM_8POINT);
    cout<<"hello!!"<<endl;
    cout << "fundamental Matrix ="<<endl<< " "  << fundamental_matrix << endl << endl;

     computeCorrespondEpilines(points1, 1, fundamental_matrix);
}
```

But I am getting error in function computeCorrespondEpilines()

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void computeCorrespondEpilines(const cv::_InputArray &, int, const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray &)
'
```

I'm not sure how to use this function and confused about 2nd and last argument.
Please point me in right direction,Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Read the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#computecorrespondepilines) Rahul, read the doc. You need another matrix, to store the results, passed as the fourth parameter.

Comment: @Adrian It worked 
Mat E; computeCorrespondEpilines(points1, 1, F, E);
Thanks mate

Comment: can anyone confirm, in this function I need to input image co-ordinates raw or normalized image co-ordinates or the undistorted image co-ordinates? Rahul seem to be putting in the raw image co-ords.